# Prove alternative ways of writing $\bar {\mathcal B} $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have to show the following 3 equalities:

1. $\bar {\mathcal B} = \{ B \cup E | B \in \mathcal B^1, E \subseteq \{-\infty, \infty\} \}$
2. $\bar {\mathcal B} =  \sigma(\{  [ -\infty, \alpha [ \:\: | \:\: \alpha \in \Bbb R \} ) = \sigma(\{  [ -\infty, \alpha ] \:\:|\:\: \alpha \in \Bbb R \} ) =\sigma(\{  ]\alpha,  \infty] \:\: | \:\:\alpha \in \Bbb R \} ) = \sigma(\{  [ \alpha,  \infty] \:\: | \:\: \alpha \in \Bbb R \} )$
3. $\bar {\mathcal B} | \Bbb R =  \mathcal B^1$

The first two make sense to me (i still don't know how to show it) but i don't really understand the third one. Also, how do you prove this formally?

Any tipps or ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$\bar {\mathcal B} |_{\Bbb R}$ is the given sigma algebra restricted to the given set, $\Bbb R$ in your case and it's defined by

$$\bar {\mathcal B} |_{\Bbb R} = \{ B \cap \Bbb R | B \in \bar {\mathcal B}\}$$

Compare to the first definition where you take elements of $\mathcal{B}^1$ and union it with $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ you now take an element of $\bar {\mathcal B}$ and  "cut" both infinities.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you also give me a hint on how to prove 1. and 2. ?